# How to create a customized page same as the OOTB osssearchresults.aspx?

Tags: search-results, refinement-panel, out-of-the-box

We are using SP2013 on-premise standard edition. There is a small site collection and make use of osssearchresults.aspx. There is one problem for osssearchresults.aspx because we have no option to edit the search result web part. We want to enable "show duplicate" option.

I have tried create a blank page and insert the search webparts. However, I don't know how to make the refinement panel show up at the left. (I want to make it look exactly like osssearchresults.aspx)

Is my only option is create a search center (as a subsite) under the site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a web part page and add the necessary search web parts. Search Box, Refinement and Results are just web parts. The query can be passed on the query string or you can include a link to this page.

Comment: But I cannot place the refinement panel at the leftmost. At the leftmost there is navigation menu. Also I cannot find any OOTB layout can do that.

Comment: Have you tried a web part page rather than a wiki page?

Comment: Later I found I can create a page with "(Welcome page)Search result" layout. It solved my problem. Thanks.